# Where to start with OpenID on Phonegap/Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, openid

I am using PhoneGap to make an app and want to authenticate users with OpenID.  I am not quite sure what to do to begin with.  Here is the library I am using:  [OpenID](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) (let me know if there is a better one you would suggest).  I understand what the code does for the most part.  Here is their sample:[SampleConsumer](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/SampleConsumer).  Where would I put all of that code and what do I need to do on the PhoneGap/JavaScript side?